# Creating array of structure

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

I have been busy with a question from a C book. The question is simple but it has some specific parts.

I would like to ask a question about arrays.
My question is about the best way with creating an array of a structure. The question wants these all;
Firstly create an array of structure. Secondly, create a linked list which connects these arrays with a restp pointer.
I want to divide my question into sub parts. First part is array of structure...
How can I create an array of a structure. I've made a research about this. And here is my way:
I'm creating a structure for my array of structure:

```
struct student{
    int id;
    struct courseList_node_s *restp;
};
```

And my linked list for completing rest of question:

```
typedef struct courseList_node_s{
    char course[6];
    int credit,
        section;
    struct courseList_node_s *restp;
}courseList_node_t;
```

I have implemented some function to handle this student schedule. 
In my get_studentList function;
I declared my array as this;

```
struct student *ansp[size];
```

And making memory allocation;

```
ansp[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct student));
```

And lastly assigning a value;

```
ansp[i]->id =id;
```

Now, my problem is while creating an array, I couldn't make it as an ordered array. For instance, the user can type 1111, 1222, 1232, and then 1011. So, my first element of array which is ansp[0] = 1011, and ansp[1] = 1111.

I couldn't figure out.

Can you give me an algorithm which consist these(Creating an ordered array of structure).

Lastly, sorry for my bad English and I may made some grammatical mistakes...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct student));` should be `sizeof coursList_node_t`.  `student` is an array of pointers to `courseList_node_t`, not a `courseList_node_t`.

Comment: I guess, an ordered array should be created after user operation, and then find the smallest -> put to array[0], find the smallest in remaining -> put to array[1], .... So you might need another parameter in student structure (e.g., bool archived) to denotes whether it is already in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd solved the problem with helps @Keith Randall and 
lserni
I have implemented both binary search tree and array of structure.

**First way, sorting array with qsort:**

I had to create a compare function:

```
int compare(const void *p1, const void *p2){
    return (* (struct student **) p1)->id - (* (struct student **) p2)->id;
}
```

And my other helper functions;

```
void get_studentList(struct student **listp,int size){
    int id,i;
    struct student *ansp[size];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("Enter student's id to exit enter -1> ");
        scanf("%d", &id);
        ansp[i] = malloc(sizeof(courseList_node_t));
        ansp[i]->id = id;
        ansp[i]->restp = NULL;
    }
    qsort (ansp, size, sizeof(struct student *), compare);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        listp[i] = ansp[i];
    }
}


courseList_node_t * insert_studentSchedule(courseList_node_t *headp, int size){
    courseList_node_t *cur_nodep;
    if(headp == NULL){
        cur_nodep = scan_course();
        headp = cur_nodep;
    } else {
        headp->restp = insert_studentSchedule(headp->restp,size);
    }
    return (headp);
}
```

And my display function;

```
void display_schedule(struct student **headp, int size){
    courseList_node_t *cur_nodep;
    int i = 0;
    while(i< size){
        cur_nodep = headp[i]->restp;
        printf("Student id > %d\n", headp[i]->id);
        while(cur_nodep != NULL){
            printf("Course name> %s\t", cur_nodep->course);
            printf("Course credit> %d\t", cur_nodep->credit);
            printf("Course section> %d\n", cur_nodep->section);
            cur_nodep = cur_nodep->restp;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Second way, Binary Search Tree:**

I changed typedef parts of my header file as this:

```
typedef struct tree_node_s{
    int id;
    struct courseList_node_s *restp;
    struct tree_node_s *leftp, *rightp;
}tree_node_t;
```

And my macro to formalize a standart pattern in dynamic allocation of nodes:

```
#define TYPED_ALLOC(type) (type *)malloc(sizeof(type))
```

And my implementation of creating a binary search tree:

```
/*
 * Insert a new id in a binary search tree. 
 * Pre: rootp points to the root node of a binary search tree
 */
tree_node_t * get_studentTree(tree_node_t *rootp, int newId)
{
    if (rootp == NULL){
        rootp = TYPED_ALLOC(tree_node_t);
        rootp->id = newId;
        rootp->restp = NULL;
        rootp->leftp = NULL;
        rootp->rightp = NULL;
    } else if ( newId == rootp->id){
        /* */
    } else if (newId < rootp->id){
        rootp->leftp = get_studentTree(rootp->leftp, newId);
    } else {
        rootp->rightp = get_studentTree(rootp->rightp, newId);
    }
    return (rootp);
}
```

This parts are not related with this question. I gave them because I want to share the partial solution of real question.

```
/*
 * Its aim to add courses to restp component of subtree
 * It may have some problems. And you can omit it. Because it not related with this question
 * Pre: elementp not empty
 */
courseList_node_t * add_course(courseList_node_t *nextp, courseList_node_t *elementp){
        if(nextp->restp == NULL){
            nextp->restp = elementp;
        } else {
            nextp->restp = add_course(nextp->restp,elementp);
        }
        return (nextp);
}

/*
 * It is not neccessary to first call get_studentTree function. It simply creates a linked list which consist of student class/lecture schedule.
 * Pre: ele and id not empty
 * Post: Tree returned includes all schedule and retains binary search tree properties.
 */
tree_node_t * insert_studentSchedule(tree_node_t *rootp,courseList_node_t *ele, int id){
    if (rootp == NULL){
        rootp = get_studentTree(rootp, id);
        rootp->restp = TYPED_ALLOC(courseList_node_t);
        strcpy(rootp->restp->course, ele->course);
        rootp->restp->credit = ele->credit;
        rootp->restp->section = ele->section;
    }
    else if(rootp->id == id){
        if ( rootp->restp == NULL ){
            rootp->restp = TYPED_ALLOC(courseList_node_t);
            strcpy(rootp->restp->course, ele->course);
            rootp->restp->credit = ele->credit;
            rootp->restp->section = ele->section;
        } else {
            rootp->restp = add_course(rootp->restp, ele);
        }

    } else if ( id < rootp->id ){
        if ( rootp->leftp != NULL )
            rootp->leftp = insert_studentSchedule(rootp->leftp, ele, id);
    } else if ( id > rootp->id ) {
        if ( rootp->rightp != NULL )
            rootp->rightp = insert_studentSchedule(rootp->rightp, ele, id);
    }
    return (rootp);
}

/*
 * Course scanning function
 */
courseList_node_t * scan_course(void){
    courseList_node_t *cur_coursep;
    char courseName[6];
    cur_coursep = (courseList_node_t *)malloc(sizeof(courseList_node_t));

    printf("Welcome to course scanning part>\n");
    printf("Enter the name of course> ");
    scanf("%s", courseName);
    strcpy(cur_coursep->course, courseName);
    printf("Enter the credit of course> ");
    scanf("%d", &cur_coursep->credit);
    printf("Enter the section of course> ");
    scanf("%d", &cur_coursep->section);
    cur_coursep->restp = NULL;

    return (cur_coursep);
}

/*
 * My way to print binary search tree with all elements
 */
void display_schedule(tree_node_t *rootp){
    courseList_node_t *cur_course;
    if(rootp == NULL)
        return;
    display_schedule(rootp->leftp);
    if (rootp->restp == NULL)
        printf("Tree with id: %d element has no member!", rootp->id);
    else {
        cur_course = rootp->restp;
        while (cur_course != NULL){
            printf("Student Id> %d\n", rootp->id);
            printf("Course name> %s\t", rootp->restp->course);
            printf("Course credit> %d\t", rootp->restp->credit);
            printf("Course section> %d\n", rootp->restp->section);
            cur_course = cur_course->restp;
        }
    }
    display_schedule(rootp->rightp);
}
```

It may not full solution of book question but with your helps, It is solution of essential parts. If you found a mistake. Feel free to add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

To order the elements, you will need to sort them.  In `C`, you probably want to use `qsort` (in `C++` there are easier ways).  You will need to define a comparison function on `struct student *` and call `qsort` on your array with it.

See [this example](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/97843-qsort-structure-array.html) for inspiration.  Note that your array is an array of structure *pointers*, the example is an array of direct structures (which is maybe what you wanted anyway?).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It helped me to solve my problem. I implemented binary search tree, too. But your way was the real solution for my problem... Thank you,

I will share my solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you give me an algorithm which consist these(Creating an ordered array of structure).

If you want to create an orderd array of structures, you probably want to build a *tree*.

There are libraries for that, but to learn and understand, you can Google 'Binary trees in C' or something like that, e.g.:

http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/Coursewww/Cwww/tree.html

Trees will allow your user to insert non-sorted values and retrieve them in sorted order (also, search them more quickly).